# Bind method result to a Silverlight XAML TextBlock

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, methods

I have a function which, given a string, returns the string translated to German, linked to the xaml I want to edit:

```
public string convert (string label) {
    return Translator.translate (label);
}
```

This string is then used to label some parts of my interface with TextBlocks in Silverlight. This is one sample TextBlock of my code:

```
 <TextBlock Text="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
```

I would wish to modify the "Text" property to call convert passing the text "Center" as a parameter and show the return result as the Text. Is there any way to do that?

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it a converter and apply it to the binding base in your `TextBlock` kind of like;

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, 
                  Converter={StaticResource YourTranslatorConverterThingy}}"/>
```

Here's just one [article](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/30/format-data-in-silverlight-databinding-valueconverter.aspx) with a bit more explanation. Hope this helps.

Comment: With your solution, do I need to have a defined property called Text? If so I'd wish to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Nah you can make it whatever you like that feeds back your content. It's just populating the `Text` of the `TextBlock`

Comment: Yeah but... how can I pass the string "Center" to that converter from the XAML?

Comment: Ha, good point! Just now realized we're talking about a `TextBlock` and not a `TextBox`, which would mean you would need to pass it the content statically anyway and just do your conversion in the back. If it's meant to be a static field to begin with why not just make it German to begin with? Or if we're talking localization, why not just do actual localization? - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838238%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: Oh and if you decide not do it with actual localization, you could also use `CallMethodAction` on the `TextBlock` to do more like what you originally asked.